# LC.exe" was not found?

Tags: windows-8, c#-2.0

currently i have changed the OS to windows 8 from Windows 7. While automation running 2005 project which refers LC.exe, wont compile successfully. But manually if i compile those project, get compiled.

please find the error i got while run those project from command prompt and also automating.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Common.targets(1679,9): error MSB3091: Task failed because "LC.exe" was not found, or the .NET Framework SDK v2.0 is not installed.  The task is looking for "LC.exe" in the "bin" subdirectory beneath the location specified in the SDKInstallRootv2.0 value of the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework.  You may be able to solve the problem by doing one of the following:  1.) Install the .NET Framework SDK v2.0.  2.) Manually set the above registry key to the correct location.  3.) Pass the correct location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task.

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Re installing the [.net framework 2.0 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19988) would resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Framework SDK 2.0 refused to re-install on my machine but I was able to fix this by [mucking about in the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761155/task-failed-because-lc-exe-was-not-found-after-upgrade-to-windows-8-1/26093607#26093607).