# Task failed because "LC.exe" was not found after upgrade to Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, windows-8.1

i have an error building my Visual Studio 2005 after i upgrade my windows 8 to windows 8.1

here's the error.

```
    Task failed because "LC.exe" was not found, or the .NET Framework SDK v2.0 is not installed.  The task is looking for "LC.exe" in the "bin" subdirectory beneath the location specified in the SDKInstallRootv2.0 value of the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework.  You may be able to solve the problem by doing one of the following:  
    1.) Install the .NET Framework SDK v2.0.  
    2.) Manually set the above registry key to the correct location.  
    3.) Pass the correct location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task.
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: have you tried to repair VS2005 under control panel->program & features?

Answer (score 5):

Adding the path to the Framework SDK into the registry solved it for me.

The relevant key is located under one of these paths:

- **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NET\Framework** (32 Bit)
- **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework** (64 Bit)

I added a string value named **`SDKInstallRootv2.0`** and set its value to the SDK path, which is probably one of the following:

- **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0**
- **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0**

Comment: This worked for me in Windows 10, version 1709 (Fall Creators Update).  The registry key to add the string value to was **_HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework_** and the location of the SDK was **_C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0_**.  Note the slight difference in the registry key compared with Ishmaeel's answer, above.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Windows 10.

1. Type regedit in command to open registry
2. Then navigate to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework**
3. Add **SDKInstallRootv2.0** string value and set it to path **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0**.
4. Save the key

I am putting the screenshot

[image]