# Task failed because "LC.exe" was not found, or the .NET Framework SDK v2.0 is not installed

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

### Anyone have the same problem with me? With visual studio 2005.

*Task failed because "LC.exe" was not found, or the .NET Framework SDK v2.0 is not installed.  The task is looking for "LC.exe" in the "bin" subdirectory beneath the location specified in the SDKInstallRootv2.0 value of the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework.  You may be able to solve the problem by doing one of the following:  1.) Install the .NET Framework SDK v2.0.  2.) Manually set the above registry key to the correct location.  3.) Pass the correct location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task*

I had done with below link but still don't work:

[Task failed because "LC.exe" was not found after upgrade to Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761155/task-failed-because-lc-exe-was-not-found-after-upgrade-to-windows-8-1)

And I downloaded the .net 2.0 sdk from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=1639 but can't install on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just fixed my issue by reinstalling VS2005. Thanks for viewing that